# Convert BufferedReader to InputStream

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I have an API with a useful method that requires an InputStream argument.  The data that I want to provide to this method is currently represented by a BufferedReader.  The library is prepared to deal with byte streams, I have character data that I'm going to feed it.

I am not changing between different encodings.

I have spent what seems an inordinate amount of time trying to discover what I was sure would be a standard way to do this, but there doesn't seem to be one.  I do NOT want to read all my data into memory, so a byte array input stream is out.

I suppose I can write one myself -- the read to my input stream would call readLine (or just read of a buffer) to get some bytes and then return an encoded array of bytes from it.  But do I have to?  Hasn't someone else already done all the calculations and error checking and all of that nonsense that is hard to get right the first time?

Comment: It sounds like _your_ library should be passing around an InputStream rather than a Reader.

Comment: Where did that other answer go?  I was logging back on to accept it.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman My library deals naturally with characters; it is reading a text file.  The library I'm using is for FTP transfers, and naturally deals in bytes.  I think both are dealing with the proper level of IO.  And I still think there should be a standard way of translating between them, or maybe there is and I just don't know about it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your title `ReaderInputStream` from [appache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) may interest you.

Comment: Beware. `ReaderInputStream` hangs when selected encoding does not support all the characters from the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com");
HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

BufferedReader rd = null;
InputStream is = huc.getInputStream();

rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

// Do Something

rd.close();
```