# Read lines from Java FileInputStream without losing my place

Tags: java, stream, bufferedreader

I have a FileInputStream.  I'd like to read character-oriented, linewise data from it, until I find a particular delimiter.  Then I'd like to pass the FileInputStream, *with the current position set immediately after the end of the delimiter line*, to a library that needs an InputStream.

I can use a BufferedReader to walk through the file a line at a time, and everything works great.  However, this leaves the underlying file stream in

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myFileStream))
```

at a non-deterministic position -- the BufferedReader had to look ahead, and I don't know how far, and AFAICT there's no way to tell the BufferedReader to rewind the underlying stream to just after the last-returned line.

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749947/convert-bufferedreader-to-inputstream) the best solution?  It seems crazy to have a `ReaderInputStream(BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(FileInputStream)))` but it's the only way I've seen to avoid rolling my own.  I'd really like to avoid writing my own entire stream-that-reads-lines implementation if at all possible.

Comment: Why not use a `Channel`?

Comment: Did you consider `InputStream.mark, reset, markSupported`? A bit cumbersome though. Maybe keep the position with a counter, close the file, and use `skip(position - 1)` or so.

Comment: Boris: how does a Channel help?  I basically want a class that implements InputStream, and has a `readLine()` method.  Barring that, I want a class with a `readLine()` method and a constructor from `InputStream`, that leaves the passed stream at the "correct" position after each `readLine()` call.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unbuffer a buffered reader.  You have to use the same wrapper for the life for the application.  In your situation I would use

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));

String line = dis.readLine();
```

While `DataInputStream.readLine()` is deprecated, it could work for you if you are careful.  Otherwise you only option is to read the bytes yourself and parse the text using the encoding required.

Comment: **If** your buffered reader can guarantee that the underlying stream supports mark, it would be simple to mark before reading a line, read the line, rewind to the mark, then skip forward by the length of the line -- presto, the underlying stream is in the "right" place.  Now, just because I say it's *simple* means that I want to build, test, and maintain it myself :-/

Comment: @Coderer But when do you mark()?  The BufferedReader could have read the line (or part of the line) you want to stop at any time in the past.  You have no guarantee as what you are marking.  The problem is you have to parse where each line ends, to know where to mark, before you have called the BufferedReader you are using to do this.

Comment: @Coderer If you have any control over the protocol, I would make it a pure binary protocol and this issue doesn't arise.

Comment: I don't.  I'm reading a file that has a variable number of header lines, then Base64-encoded data.  I want to read the header lines, then pass a stream of base64-encoded text to a Commons-Codec `Base64InputStream` constructor. I can't change the file format, and I want to write / maintain as little of the processing logic as necessary.

Comment: What you can do is to read further lines and pass `line.getBytes()` to the `Base64` decoder and this should work.  Mixing binary and text is bound to be unpleasant and error prone which is why I suggest you avoid it if possible.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the `ReaderInputStream` is the way to go here -- the Base64InputStream really *should* have a Reader constructor, because Base64-encoded stuff really is printable characters.  Since it doesn't, I think the next best thing is to give it an InputStream that's actually based on characters, which is what a `ReaderInputStream` does.